# I have to add edittext input at city position and add it to url

Tags: android

/* Here the last parameter is taken from edittext but it is not adding input from

edittext */ Please check:

http://103.75.33.98/BPService/GetAllBPService.svc/GetSalesPersonNo/CBS/NOIDA/ADMIN

package com.example.administrator.spinnerval;

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SalesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    List<String> salesPeName = new ArrayList<String>();
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    BufferedReader reader;
    ProgressDialog pdLoading;
    String username = "CBS";
    String password = "NOIDA";
    String city="" ;
    String myurl;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    URL url;
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView;
    //String url="http://103.75.33.98/BPService/GetAllBPService.svc/GetSalesPersonNo/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales);
        acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete2);
        acTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selection = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
               // city=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                city=acTextView.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        myurl="http://103.75.33.98/BPService/GetAllBPService.svc/GetSalesPersonNo";

        String res = new StringBuilder(14).append(myurl).append("/").append(username).append("/").append(password).toString();
        String result=new StringBuilder(14).append(res).append("/").append(city).toString();
        try {
             url=new URL(result);
            Log.d("url",url.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter = new
                ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, salesPeName);
        //acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
           new SalesTask().execute(city);


    }


    private class SalesTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                 //url = new URL("http://103.75.33.98/BPService/GetAllBPService.svc/GetSalesPersonNo/"+username+"/"+password+"/"+city);

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.e("url reference value",url.toString());
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                String line = "";
                Log.d("bufferData", buffer.toString());

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);

                }
                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            String jsonString = buffer.toString();
            // Log.e("Final Json that we have", jsonString);
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                JSONObject obj1 = obj.getJSONObject("GetBPSalesPersonResult");
                JSONArray jArray = obj1.getJSONArray("BPResult");

                for (int i = 0; i <= jArray.length(); i++) {

                    salesPeName.add(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("SALES_PERSON_NO"));
                    Log.e("Location",salesPeName.toString());
                    acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat is printing url as :
url: http://103.75.33.98/BPService/GetAllBPService.svc/GetSalesPersonNo/CBS/NOIDA/

Comment: Please, reformat your question. That Exception is not from the code you wrote, but from a HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream You will have to provide the part of the code with the InputStream

Comment: The response is json right?, Show the code in which you call the url

Comment: format your question please. It makes my eyes bleed while reading it, and I completle loose all the will to help you.

Comment: I have formatted my question,now please check it.Here I want to add my string parameter to url and then want to call asynctask .But each time I got stuck with incomplete url.Please help me.

Comment: Ale,I formated my code.Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but you are adding undeclared variables to the url. I think it should be:

```
URL url = new URL("http://103.75.33.98/BPService/GetAllBPService.svc/GetSalesPersonNo/"+cbs+"/"+city+"/"+saleP);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create the Url on in onCreate, at witch time city="", and you change the city in onItemClick: city=acTextView.getText().toString(), you need to generate the URL in onItemClick and call new SalesTask().execute(city); not right away

```
acTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selection = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            city = acTextView.getText().toString();
            url = new URL(new StringBuilder(myurl).append("/").append(username).append("/").append(password).append("/").append(city).toString());
            new SalesTask().execute(city);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used it like u suggested but nothing happening.Even Log is not showing any error